# error Domain=FMDatabase Code=8 "attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

I'm using FMDatabase library to used prepped database sqlite.

I got this error:

```
Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=8 "attempt to write a readonly database" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=attempt to write a readonly database}
2017-10-27 19:59:10.983238+0330 kashanmap[417:63718] Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (8: attempt to write a readonly database) eu
2017-10-27 19:59:10.983473+0330 kashanmap[417:63718] DB Query: insert into LocationInfoFa
```

it's my class:

```
import FMDB
class DatabaseManager {

    private let dbFileName = "kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db"
    private var database:FMDatabase!

    let TABLE_LOCATION_FA           = "LocationInfoFa";
    let TABLE_LOCATION_EN           = "LocationInfoEn";
    let TABLE_GREAT_PEOPLE_FA       = "GreatPeopleInfoFa";
    let TABLE_GREAT_PEOPLE_EN       = "GreatPeopleInfoEn";
    let TABLE_TAGS                  = "Tags";
    let TABLE_RELATION_TAG_LOCATION = "RelationTagLocation";
    let TABLE_NECESSARY_INFORMATION = "NecessaryInformation";
    let TABLE_SLIDER_FA             = "SliderFa";
    let TABLE_SLIDER_EN             = "SliderEn";
    let DATABASE_VERSION            = 4;
    static var LANGUAGE                    = 1 ; //1:Fa , 2:En
    var utilities                   = Utilities()

    init() {
        openDatabase()

        if(utilities.getData(key: "lang") == "2")
        {
            DatabaseManager.LANGUAGE = 2
        }

    }

    func openDatabase() {

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let dbPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths).appendingPathComponent(dbFileName)
        let str_path = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent(dbFileName).path
        let database = FMDatabase(path: str_path)

        /* Open database read-only. */
        if (!(database.open(withFlags: 2))) {
            print("Could not open database at \(dbPath).")
        } else {
            print("opened database")
            self.database = database;
        }
    }

    func closeDatabase() {
        if (database != nil) {
            database.close()
        }
    }
```

path of my database:

[image]

my query:

```
do {
        let db = database

        let q = try db?.executeUpdate("insert into \(table) (catid,subcat_id,id,subcat_title,title,description,lat,lon,takhfif,images,wifi,apple_health,wc,full_time,pos,work_hours,phone,mobile,fax,website,email,address,facebook,instagram,linkedin,telegram,googleplus,twitter,publish,feature,manager,city,rating_sum,rate_count,lastip,parking,isMallID,mallID,discount_images,price_images,newProduct_images,services_images,order_online,out_upon,cat_title,cat_icon,last_modify,item_logo,cat_logo,rate_sum1,rate_sum2,rate_sum3,rate_count1,rate_count2,rate_count3,rate_title1,rate_title2,rate_title3,rate_enable,installments_text,installments_image) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values:[ catid,subcat_id,id,subcat_title,title,description,lat,lon,takhfif,images,wifi,apple_health,wc,full_time,pos,work_hours,phone,mobile,fax,website,email,address,facebook,instagram,linkedin,telegram,googleplus,twitter,publish,feature,manager,city,rating_sum,rate_count,lastip,parking,isMallID,mallID,discount_images,price_images,newProduct_images,services_images,order_online,out_upon,cat_title,cat_icon,last_modify,item_logo,cat_logo,rate_sum1,rate_sum2,rate_sum3,rate_count1,rate_count2,rate_count3,rate_title1,rate_title2,rate_title3,rate_enable,installments_text,installments_image])

    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
```

there are some solutions in stack overflow but them don't accepted as true answer.

**updated2**

I got this error:

```
DB does not exist in documents folder
```

my code:

```
   init() {
        openDatabase()

        if(utilities.getData(key: "lang") == "2")
        {
            DatabaseManager.LANGUAGE = 2
        }

    }

    func copyDatabaseIfNeeded() {
        // Move database file from bundle to documents folder

        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        let documentsUrl = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                            in: .userDomainMask)

        guard documentsUrl.count != 0 else {
            return // Could not find documents URL
        }

        let finalDatabaseURL = documentsUrl.first!.appendingPathComponent("kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db")

        if !( (try? finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false) {
            print("DB does not exist in documents folder")

            let documentsURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db")

            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: (documentsURL?.path)!, toPath: finalDatabaseURL.path)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Couldn't copy file to final location! Error:\(error.description)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Database file found at path: \(finalDatabaseURL.path)")
        }

    }

    func openDatabase() {

        self.copyDatabaseIfNeeded()

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let dbPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths).appendingPathComponent(dbFileName)
        let str_path = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent(dbFileName).path
        let database = FMDatabase(path: str_path)

        /* Open database read-only. */
        if (!(database.open(withFlags: 2))) {
            print("Could not open database at \(dbPath).")
        } else {
            print("opened database")
            self.database = database;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite ios : attempt to write a readonly database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000311/sqlite-ios-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this error because you are trying to write (update) the *.db* file in the **bundle** directory which is *not* allowed:

> **AppName.app:**
>
> This is the app’s bundle. This directory contains the app and all of
> its resources. **You cannot write to this directory**. To prevent
> tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time.
> Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your app
> from launching. You can, however, **gain read-only access to any**
> **resources stored in the apps bundle**.
>
> <sub>[File System Basics - Table 1-1:  Commonly used directories of an iOS app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)</sub>

If you are aiming to update the file, you should implement a logic to *copy* it -if it's not already has been copied before- into the *documents* directory, thus you'd be able to read/write transactions with the copied file.

*Remark* that for iOS 11 and above, you might want to copy the database file into the *Application Support* directory if you don't want to let be viewable to the end users when navigating to your app by the *Files* iOS app. For details, check the [iOS Storage Best Practices Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/204/) video session.

You'd notice that this logic should be applied to any file in the app main bundle, for instance it is also [applicable for JSON files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541166/swift-writetofile-does-not-update-json-file-in-mainbundle).

Comment: I  find this solution: https://gist.github.com/rd13/320b3fed4d5f10ab8ea833b3f9818980 
where should  I call this function ?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Such a function should be called on the AppDelegate, `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian That code should be done in the `openDatabase` method of your `DatabaseManager` class. Do not call it from the app delegate.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the advice, you could please describe why?

Comment: @AhmadF Because the `DatabaseManager` is the owner of the database. All of the logic associated with the database belongs in that class. Why clutter up the app delegate with code it should know nothing about?

Comment: @rmaddy that's right, the function itself should be implemented in the `DatabaseManager` and *called* -by `DatabaseManager`- in the AppDelegate, that's what I meant. what am I asking about is: why to call it each time when opening the database instead of one time after the app finish launching?